# How to get probability if two strings means the same

Tags: python, nltk

I already visited almost every posts related to this but most of them are calculating the probability on basis of similar words but is there any way of getting the probability if two statements are same in meaning but may contain different words. Eg. "Python is the right option for ML" and "Best language for Machine Learning is Python". This example should return True( the probability should be atleast 0.5 in this) as both the sentences means the same.

In this code its just calculating the similarity using similar words present in both the strings.

```python
# Program to measure the similarity between 
# two sentences using cosine similarity. 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

# X = input("Enter first string: ").lower() 
# Y = input("Enter second string: ").lower() 
X ="I love horror movies"
Y ="Lights out is a horror movie"

# tokenization 
X_list = word_tokenize(X) 
Y_list = word_tokenize(Y) 

# sw contains the list of stopwords 
sw = stopwords.words('english') 
l1 =[];l2 =[] 

# remove stop words from the string 
X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw} 
Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw} 

# form a set containing keywords of both strings 
rvector = X_set.union(Y_set) 
for w in rvector: 
    if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector 
    else: l1.append(0) 
    if w in Y_set: l2.append(1) 
    else: l2.append(0) 
c = 0

# cosine formula 
for i in range(len(rvector)): 
        c+= l1[i]*l2[i] 
cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5) 
print("similarity: ", cosine)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide more information with regards to what you have tried to far and what you wish to achieve with sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I hope you will get it now.

Comment: There are a lot of gotchas in what you're doing.  You're talking about requiring an understanding of English grammar.  And technically speaking, those two statements do NOT mean the same thing; the CEO controls a company, but does not OWN the company.

Comment: Have a look at this python package known as gensim. https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/

Comment: If you happen to finish coding the heruculean task of teaching an AI/ML system to reason about what the meaning of wirtten language is and decide on similarity - you should take it and make it a sellable product. Asking for software that already does this would be offtopic as asking for 3rd party suggestions that are offsite.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It should guide you on how to work with text semantics using word embeddings.

Comment: @patrick and Tim, while both of you are technically correct, there are models available (open source, ready to use) which allow a significant amount of semantics in text analysis. NLP field in ML these days has reached human level semantic understanding (surpassed in some cases). In my answer I only use a method which has been available since 2012. More advance models like BERT and it’s variants perform a thousand fold better, not to mention GPT-3, which is borderline magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with text semantics, you will have to work with algorithms that deal with it such as word2vec, glove, fasttext.

You can use pre-trained word embedding that has been trained on a lot of data and encodes the contextual/semantic similarities between words based on their co-occurrence with other words in sentences.

These word embeddings are `n-dimensional vector` representations of a large vocabulary of words. These vectors can be summed up to create a representation of the sentence's embedding. Sentences with word with similar semantics will have similar vectors, and thus their sentence embeddings will also be similar.

You can check similarity between these sentence embeddings using `cosine_similarity`

```
from scipy import spatial
import gensim.downloader as api

model = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-50") #choose from multiple models https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data

s0 = 'Mark zuckerberg owns the facebook company'
s1 = 'Facebook company ceo is mark zuckerberg'
s2 = 'Microsoft is owned by Bill gates'
s3 = 'How to learn japanese'

def preprocess(s):
    return [i.lower() for i in s.split()]

def get_vector(s):
    return np.sum(np.array([model[i] for i in preprocess(s)]), axis=0)


print('s0 vs s1 ->',1 - spatial.distance.cosine(get_vector(s0), get_vector(s1)))
print('s0 vs s2 ->', 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(get_vector(s0), get_vector(s2)))
print('s0 vs s3 ->', 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(get_vector(s0), get_vector(s3)))
```

```
#Semantic similarity between sentence pairs
s0 vs s1 -> 0.965923011302948
s0 vs s2 -> 0.8659112453460693
s0 vs s3 -> 0.5877998471260071
```

You can choose better models than the one I used from here - https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data

Comment: Note, you can use average instead of summing vectors if there is too large a variation in sentence lengths.

Comment: Another note, cosine similarity is not to be mixed with probability, it is a measure that ranges from -1 to 1. Meaning if the 2 sentences have no relationship between them then score will be around 0.